# StringUtils.replaceEach: Replace only separate words but not substring

Tags: java, replace, apache-stringutils

I need to use **Apache**'s `StringUtils.replaceEach()` method for replacing set of strings. However, this methods also replaces substrings in the word. I know I can use `replaceAll` method with `\b` regex. But I wanted to know if there's a way to tell `StringUtils` to not replace substrings.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

`StringUtils` class is envisioned to operate on strings in general. Yet, you can have a look at the source code:

https://github.com/apache/commons-lang/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.java#L5749

There is also [WordUtils](https://github.com/apache/commons-lang/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.java) class but it also does not contain what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `StringUtils.repeat()`, more info can be found to [github](https://github.com/apache/commons-lang/pull/362/files).

Answer (score 0):

Don't think there's a flag for `StringUtils` but one possible hack would be to surround your replacement set with spaces. So instead of `"foo" -> "bar"`, you'd have `" foo " -> " bar "`. This sadly isn't very helpful if your input may have new lines etc. instead of just spaces between words.